# Lifting methods to function values in Scala

Tags: scala

Does the Scala library provide any support for lifting a method of a given type to a function value?

For example, suppose I want to lift `String.length`.  I can write

```
val f: String => Int = _.length
```

or

```
val f = { s: String => s.length }
```

However, this syntax is not always ideal (particularly in the midst of a larger expression). I think I'm looking for something that will enable expressions like

```
Lift[String](_.length)
Lift[Option[Int]].lift(_.filter)
```

and I have in mind something like this:

```
class Lift[T] {                                                          
   def apply[R](f: T => R): T => R = f

   def lift[A, R](f: (T) => (A) => R): (T, A) => R = 
         f(_)(_) 
   def lift[A1, A2, R](f: (T) => (A1, A2) => R): (T, A1, A2) => R =
         f(_)(_,_)
   // ... etc. ...
}
object Lift {
   def apply[T] = new Lift[T]
}
```

**Question 1:** *Does the standard library (or any library) provide something like this?*

**Question 2:** If not, *is it possible to write it in such a way that `Option.filter` can be lifted as above* (rather than as `Lift[Option[Int]].lift[Int => Boolean, Option[Int]](_.filter)`)? Without supplying the type parameters on the `lift` method I get the following error:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.filter)
       Lift[Option[Int]].lift(_.filter)
                              ^
```

*Update*:

Apparently, the problem I'm running in to has something to do with the overloaded `lift` method.  If I rename the overloads, I *can* lift `Option.filter` without all the extra type parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution that I'm happy with. This version supports simple syntax and a single entry point to the API, while also providing control over the form of the lifted function (i.e. uncurried, partly curried, or fully curried).

**Examples**:

I'll use the following class definition in the examples below:

```
class Foo {
   def m1: Int = 1
   def m2(i: Int): Int = i
   def m3(i: Int, j: Int): Int = i + j
}
```

The simplest form of lifting is to return the method as a partially applied function, equivalent to invoking `((_: Foo).method _)`:

```
scala> lift[Foo](_.m1)                         // NOTE: trailing _ not required
res0: (Foo) => Int = <function1>

scala> lift[Foo](_.m2 _)                       // NOTE: trailing _ required
res1: (Foo) => (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> lift[Foo](_.m3 _)
res2: (Foo) => (Int, Int) => Int = <function1> // NOTE: the result is partly curried
```

By importing some implicits, one can request curried or uncurried forms:

```
scala> {                        
     | import CurriedLiftables._
     | lift[Foo](_.m3 _)        
     | }
res3: (Foo) => (Int) => (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> {                          
     | import UncurriedLiftables._
     | lift[Foo](_.m3 _)          
     | }
res4: (Foo, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>
```

Implementation:

```
class Lift[T] {
   def apply[R,F](f: T => R)(implicit e: (T => R) Liftable F): F = e.lift(f)
}
object lift {
   def apply[T] = new Lift[T]
}

class Liftable[From, To](val lift: From => To)

class DefaultLiftables {
   implicit def lift[F]: F Liftable F = new Liftable(identity)
}
object Liftable extends DefaultLiftables

class UncurriedLiftable1 extends DefaultLiftables {
   implicit def lift1[T, A, R]: (T => A => R) Liftable ((T, A) => R) = 
      new Liftable( f => f(_)(_) )
}
class UncurriedLiftable2 extends UncurriedLiftable1 {
   implicit def lift2[T, A1, A2, R]: (T => (A1, A2) => R) Liftable ((T, A1, A2) => R) = 
      new Liftable ( f => f(_)(_,_) )
}
// UncurriedLiftable3, UncurriedLiftable4, ...
object UncurriedLiftables extends UncurriedLiftable2

class CurriedLiftable2 extends DefaultLiftables {
   implicit def lift2[T, A1, A2, R]: (T => (A1, A2) => R) Liftable (T => A1 => A2 => R) =
      new Liftable( f => (x: T) => (a1: A1) => (a2: A2) => f(x)(a1, a2) )
}
// CurriedLiftable3, CurriedLiftable4, ...
object CurriedLiftables extends CurriedLiftable2
```

---

My previous solution required a separate lift method for each arity:

```
import Lift._
val f1 = lift0[String](_.length)
val f2 = lift1[Option[Int]](_.filter)
val f3 = lift2[Either[String, Int]](_.fold)
```

Implementation:

```
class Lift0[T] {
   def apply[R](f: T => R): T => R = f
}
class Lift1[T] {
   def apply[A, R](f: (T) => (A) => R): (T, A) => R = 
      f(_)(_) 
}
class Lift2[T] {
   def apply[A1, A2, R](f: (T) => (A1, A2) => R): (T, A1, A2) => R =
      f(_)(_,_)
}
// ... etc. ...

object Lift {
   def lift0[T] = new Lift0[T]
   def lift1[T] = new Lift1[T]
   def lift2[T] = new Lift2[T]
   // ... etc. ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

What is the problem with

```
(_: String).length
(_: Option[Int]).filter _
```

?

Comment: That should be (_: Option[Int]).filter _ (mind the trailing underscore!)

Comment: Not bad.  I'm hoping to get a fully uncurried form, but I may have to settle for this.

Comment: I came up with a solution that provides a single lift function with syntax at least as simple as this, but that also gives the caller control over the form of the lifted function (curried, partly curried, or uncurried). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160239/lifting-methods-in-scala/4168990#4168990 if you're interested.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, how can I read the result of the latter function in your answer? In my example, I set g() equal to it.
`scala> g(Some(3))
res23: (Int => Boolean) => Option[Int] = <function1>`

Comment: @Kevin It needs more parameter lists. For example, `g(Some(3))(_ % 2== 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

Passing in filter as partially applied method seems to do the job:

```
scala> class Lift[T] {                                        
     |    def apply[R](f: T => R): T => R = f
     | }
defined class Lift

scala> object Lift {
     |    def apply[T] = new Lift[T]
     | }
defined module Lift

scala> val ls = Lift[String](_.length)
ls: (String) => Int = <function1>

scala> val los = Lift[Option[Int]](_.filter _)     
los: (Option[Int]) => ((Int) => Boolean) => Option[Int] = <function1>
```

Comment: This works, but I was hoping to get a `(Option[Int], (Int) => Boolean) => Option[Int]`.

Comment: I came up with a solution that provides a single lift function with simple syntax, but that also gives the caller control over the form of the lifted function (curried, partly curried, or uncurried). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160239/lifting-methods-in-scala/4168990#4168990 if you're interested.