# Is it possible in Scala to force the caller to specify a type parameter for a polymorphic method?

Tags: generics, scala, type-inference

```
//API
class Node
class Person extends Node

object Finder
{
  def find[T <: Node](name: String): T = doFind(name).asInstanceOf[T]
}

//Call site (correct)
val person = find[Person]("joe")

//Call site (dies with a ClassCast inside b/c inferred type is Nothing)
val person = find("joe")
```

In the code above the client site "forgot" to specify the type parameter, as the API writer I *want* that to mean "just return Node". Is there any way to define a generic method (not a class) to achieve this (or equivalent).  Note: using a manifest inside the implementation to do the cast if (manifest != scala.reflect.Manifest.Nothing) won't compile ... I have a nagging feeling that some Scala Wizard knows how to use Predef.<:< for this :-)

Ideas ?

Comment: @Ben, thx for your correction to my initial sloppy post :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yet another solution is to specify a default type for the parameter as follows:

```
object Finder {
   def find[T <: Node](name: String)(implicit e: T DefaultsTo Node): T = 
      doFind(name).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

The key is to define the following *phantom type* to act as a witness for the default:

```
sealed class DefaultsTo[A, B]
trait LowPriorityDefaultsTo {
   implicit def overrideDefault[A,B] = new DefaultsTo[A,B]
}
object DefaultsTo extends LowPriorityDefaultsTo {
   implicit def default[B] = new DefaultsTo[B, B]
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it avoids the error altogether (at both run-time and compile-time).  If the caller does not specify the type parameter, it defaults to `Node`.

**Explanation**:

The signature of the `find` method ensures that it can only be called if the caller can supply an object of type `DefaultsTo[T, Node]`. Of course, the `default` and `overrideDefault` methods make it easy to create such an object for any type `T`. Since these methods are implicit, the compiler automatically handles the business of calling one of them and passing the result into `find`.

*But how does the compiler know which method to call?* It uses its type inference and implicit resolution rules to determine the appropriate method. There are three cases to consider:

1. `find` is called with no type parameter. In this case, type `T` must be inferred. Searching for an implicit method that can provide an object of type `DefaultsTo[T, Node]`, the compiler finds `default` and `overrideDefault`. `default` is chosen since it has priority (because it's defined in a proper subclass of the trait that defines `overrideDefault`). As a result, `T` must be bound to `Node`.
2. `find` is called with a non-`Node` type parameter (e.g., `find[MyObj]("name")`). In this case, an object of type `DefaultsTo[MyObj, Node]` must be supplied. Only the `overrideDefault` method can supply it, so the compiler inserts the appropriate call.
3. `find` is called with `Node` as the type parameter. Again, either method is applicable, but `default` wins due to its higher priority.

Comment: This improves on the previous chosen answer, pretty much does everything one would want to. Giving it the Check.  Thanx Aaron.

Comment: This referred to by Akka Concurrency book. This is nice. But I don't understand the reason for `LowPriorityDefaultsTo` trait... would be nice to get a for-dummies explanation of this (maybe a blog post)?

Comment: @drozzy I added an explanation to the answer -- briefly, the `LowPriorityDefaultsTo` trait is necessary to avoid ambiguity since either `default` or `overrideDefault` could provide an object of type `DefaultsTo[A, A]`. Putting `overrideDefault` in a trait causes the compiler to prefer `default` in any situation where either method would do.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this solution to default a type parameter that can be inferred from an argument? Given method `foo[T](t: T)`, can we force T to be explicit?

Comment: @stewSquared If you haven't already, I would suggest looking for or posting a separate question about that.

Comment: There is something I don't understand here. For this to work, it is necessary that the compiler searches for the implicit values before it infers the types. But to search for the implicit values it needs to know the types. So, what happens first?

Comment: @Readren Type inference is only involved in case 1 described in the answer. In that case, the compiler searches for an implicit value of type `DefaultsTo[T, Node]`, where `T` is unconstrained.  Such a value can be constructed in two ways (with `default` or `overrideDefault`). Because `default` is expressly prioritized over `overrideDefault`, the compiler infers that `DefaultsTo[T, Node]` must unify with `DefaultsTo[B, B]` (where `T` and `B` are both unbound). Thus, it binds type variable `B` to `Node` and, in turn, type variable `T` to `Node` (_inferring_ `T = Node`).

Answer (score 8):

Miles Sabin [posted a really nice solution](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Default-type-parameters-tp3169946p3170297.html) for this problem on the scala-user mailing list.  Define a `NotNothing` type class as follows:

```
sealed trait NotNothing[T] { type U }                                          
object NotNothing {
   implicit val nothingIsNothing = new NotNothing[Nothing] { type U = Any }
   implicit def notNothing[T] = new NotNothing[T] { type U = T }           
}
```

Now you can define your `Finder` as

```
object Finder {
   def find[T <: Node : NotNothing](name: String): T = 
      doFind(name).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

If you try to invoke `Finder.find` without a type parameter, you'll get a compile-time error:

> error: ambiguous implicit values:
>    both method notNothing in object $iw of type [T]java.lang.Object with NotNothing[T]{type U = T}
>    and value nothingIsNothing in object $iw of type => java.lang.Object with NotNothing[Nothing]{type U = Any}
>    match expected type NotNothing[T]
>          Finder.find("joe")

This solution is far more general than the ones proposed in my other answers.  The only drawback I can see is that the compile-time error is pretty opaque, and the `@implicitNotFound` annotation doesn't help.

Comment: I've logged https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6806 to lobby for an @ambiguousImplicits annotation for these cases.  Vote for it!

Comment: It actually works only if you declare polymorphic parameter in your method : `def find[T : NotNothing](name: String, whatever: T): T` but in this case `def find[T : NotNothing](name: String): T` you can make a statement `obj.find("bla")` and the compiler doesn't throw the ambiguous error and it crashes at runtime `not an instance of scala.runtime.Nothing`

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to get what you're after, but it's not simple.  The problem is that without an explicit type parameter, the compiler can only infer that `T` is `Nothing`.  In that case, you want `find` to return something of type `Node`, *not* of type `T` (i.e. `Nothing`), but in every other case you want find to return something of type `T`.

When you want your return type to vary based on a type parameter, you can use a technique similar to the one I used in my [method lifting API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160239/lifting-methods-in-scala/4168990#4168990).

```
object Finder {
   def find[T <: Node] = new Find[T]

   class Find[T <: Node] {
       def apply[R](name: String)(implicit e: T ReturnAs R): R = 
          doFind(name).asInstanceOf[R]
   }

   sealed class ReturnAs[T, R]
   trait DefaultReturns {
      implicit def returnAs[T] = new ReturnAs[T, T]
   }
   object ReturnAs extends DefaultReturns {
      implicit object returnNothingAsNode extends ReturnAs[Nothing, Node]
   }
}
```

Here, the `find` method returns a polymorphic functor that, when applied to a name, will return an object of either type `T` or of type `Node` depending on the value of the `ReturnAs` argument supplied by the compiler.  If `T` is `Nothing`, the compiler will supply the `returnNothingAsNode` object and the apply method will return a `Node`.  Otherwise, the compiler will supply a `ReturnAs[T, T]`, and the apply method will return a `T`.

---

Riffing off of Paul's solution on the mailing list, another possibility is to provide an implicit for each type that "works".  Instead of returning a `Node` when the type parameter is omitted, a compile error will be issued:

```
object Finder {
   def find[T : IsOk](name: String): T = 
      doFind(name).asInstanceOf[T]

   class IsOk[T]
   object IsOk {
      implicit object personIsOk extends IsOk[Person]
      implicit object nodeIsOk extends IsOk[Node]
   }
}
```

Of course, this solution does not scale well.

Comment: An alternative solution using a special "Domain Bottom Type" was proposed by Paul Philips in the Scala mailing list, see it here http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/21986

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how that solves the problem you posed here.  Casting a `Person` to `BottomNode` wouldn't work any better than casting a `Person` to `Nothing`.

Comment: Casting, no. But using a BottomNode marker trait which *all* domain types *must* mix in, would allow the lower bound to be established, the courtesy cast when no parameter is provided (would be impossible with a lower bound) still requires your solution.  At this point your solution (a bit prettied up) is the one we'll end up using most likely :-)

Comment: @Alex Having all domain types mix in `BottomNode` is not really any different from having them all inherit `Node`. It allows you to establish an upper bound `T <: BottomNode`, but since `BottomNode` is not a subtype of all domain types it would not establish a lower bound `T >: BottomNode`.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's solution provides a lower bound on T, so val person = find("joe") is a compile-time error, forcing you to explicitly state the type (e.g., Node). But it's a rather awful solution (Paul explicitly said he wasn't recommending it) since it requires you to enumerate all your subtypes.

Comment: I agree, a diff. implementation of Paul's idea would be to have a single marker trait that all the types in the domain mix in must mix in which will serve as a reasonable lower bound. I haven't tested this yet, but I will in a few weeks once the current fire in an unrelated system is put out. If that doesn't work, I'll revert to using Aaron's suggestion above.

Comment: Jim, I suggest you try it.  Adding a lower bound, say `BottomNode`, on `T` doesn't make `val person = find("joe")` a compile-time error.  It just changes the inferred type from `Nothing` to `BottomNode`, and still results in a run-time error.  The reason `val dog = kennel` does not compile in Paul's code is because there is no implicit `BottomDog` object in scope. Using implicits in that way doesn't work if you have more than one instance of each type (as is presumably the case for a String-based lookup).

Comment: @Aaron, hmmm ... I must confess I was rash in posting my comment above. You are correct ! Seems like there's no alternative to "Lifting" as you call it the method to the Functor.