# Default type for method calls

Tags: generics, scala, types, type-parameter

I would like to know how if it is possible to have a default type when calling a type-parameterized method in Scala. Suppose I have the following method somewhere:

```
def apply[A]( id: String )( implicit processor: Processor[A] ) =
  processor( data get id )
```

I would like `A` to be `String`, when the compiler has no hints about what type to infer. So I can overload my definition with:

```
def apply( id: String )( implicit processor: Processor[String] ) =
  processor( data get id )
```

But both methods will have the same signature after erasure... Is there any way to provide a default type ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining the following phantom type:

```
sealed class DefaultsTo[A, B]
trait LowPriorityDefaultsTo {
   implicit def overrideDefault[A,B] = new DefaultsTo[A,B]
}
object DefaultsTo extends LowPriorityDefaultsTo {
   implicit def default[B] = new DefaultsTo[B, B]
}
```

Then your method can be written

```
def apply[A]( id: String )( implicit e: A DefaultsTo String,
                                     processor: Processor[A] ) =
   processor( data get id )
```

The definition of `overrideDefault` guarantees that for any two specified types, `A` and `B`, the compiler can always supply an object of type `DefaultsTo[A, B]` (e.g. `DefaultsTo[Int, String]`).  However, if one of the two types are unspecified (e.g. `DefaultsTo[A, String]`), the compiler will prefer to identify the two types (supplying, in the example, `DefaultsTo[String, String]`, and thus inferring `String` for the unspecified type `A`).

As [Naftoli Gugenheim pointed out in this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/u1IUxTYLE8M/discussion), you can also achieve some nice syntax for use with context bounds:

```
class Has[B] {
   type AsDefault[A] = A DefaultsTo B
}

def apply[A : Has[String]#AsDefault : Processor](id: String) =
   implicitly[Processor[A]].apply(data get id)
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403906/is-it-possible-in-scala-to-force-the-caller-to-specify-a-type-parameter-for-a-pol) for related techniques.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use a little trick

```
class C {
   def apply[A](id: String) = (processor: Processor[A]) => id + processor
   def apply(id: String)(implicit processor: Processor[String]) = id + processor
}
```

In a more general context, no idea sry...

**EDIT**

I forgot you need the `processor` to be `implicit` so it won't compile...

Comment: That doesn't work if he wants the compiler to implicitly supply the Processor.