# Is infix notation allowed in declarations of a parameterized type in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit, infix-notation, parametric-polymorphism

I have been trying to understand the answers given to the question asked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403906/is-it-possible-in-scala-to-force-the-caller-to-specify-a-type-parameter-for-a-po/6629984#6629984).

The code below reproduces the solution proposed in the accepted answer.

```
object Finder {
  def find[T <: Node](name: String)(implicit e: T DefaultsTo Node): T = 
    doFind(name).asInstanceOf[T]
}    

sealed class DefaultsTo[A, B]
trait LowPriorityDefaultsTo {
  implicit def overrideDefault[A,B] = new DefaultsTo[A,B]
}
object DefaultsTo extends LowPriorityDefaultsTo {
   implicit def default[B] = new DefaultsTo[B, B]
}
```

I would understand it if the implicit were defined as

```
(implicit e:  DefaultsTo[T, Node])
```

But instead it is defined in something that looks like infix notation. I never knew that a type `DefaultsTo[T, Node]` could be written as `T DefaultsTo Node`. Is this what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But instead it is defined in something that looks like infix notation. I never knew that a type DefaultsTo[T,Node] could be written as "T DefaultsTo Node". Is this what is going on ?

Yes. The rule is very simple: the type must have precisely 2 parameters. It's primarily intended for types with symbolic names like `<:<`, but as you can see it works for alphanumeric names as well.

[Scala specification, 3.2.8 Infix Types](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html):

> ```
> InfixType     ::=  CompoundType {id [nl] CompoundType}
> ```
>
> An infix type `T1 op T2` consists of an infix operator `op` which gets applied to two type operands `T1` and `T2`. The type is equivalent to the type application `op[T1,T2]`. The infix operator `op` may be an arbitrary identifier.
>
> All type infix operators have the same precedence; parentheses have to be used for grouping. The associativity of a type operator is determined as for term operators: type operators ending in a colon ‘:’ are right-associative; all other operators are left-associative.
>
> In a sequence of consecutive type infix operations `t0 op t1 op2 … opn tn`, all operators `op1,…,opn` must have the same associativity. If they are all left-associative, the sequence is interpreted as `(…(t0 op1 t1) op2…) opn tn`, otherwise it is interpreted as `t0 op1 (t1 op2 (…opn tn)…)`.

Comment: Another good example is Scalaz's [disjunction](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Either.html).

Comment: curiosity satisfied !     Thank you, Alexey.     And also, thanks, Chris. I looked at Scalaz's disjunction, and i see that  the trait  \/[A,B]   can be used like this   swap( disjunction: A \/ B)     which I understand now is equivalent to  swap(disjunction:   \/[A,B]).   Certainly it is more  intuitive and readable in the first declaration.    I'm still curious to see a write-up of this rule if anyone has a link.   regards /chris

Comment: Another good example is shapeless `HList`: e.g. `Int :: Double :: String :: HNil` would be written `::[Int, ::[Double, ::[String, HNil]]]`.

Comment: I've added the relevant section of the Scala specification.